# Matching two collections based on one field and copying data from a field in second collection to first one if they match

Tags: mongodb

There are currently two collections, lets call them collection A and collection B.

Collection A has field f1, f2, f3 ,f4 ,f5

Collection B has fields , f1, f6

(the f1 in collection A and collection B has the same data)

What i'm trying to do is to to write field 6 to collection A based on a match on f1.

As in for every document that has the same value for f1 in A and B collection, copy data from f6 to a new field called f6 (or f7) in collection A.

There are several of the same documents with the same f1 value in both collection, but different f6 value in collection B, even if f1 is the same.

Whats the best way to go about this ?

example

Collection A document is

```
f1: 101
f2: 102
f3: 103
f4: 104
f5: 106
```

and second collection A document

```
f1: 101
f2: 105
f3: 106
f4: 107
f5: 108
```

collection B document

```
f1: 101
f2: 1025
```

second collection B document

```
f1: 101
f2: 1026
```

And I want to make a new field in collection A, f6 which would have the same data from collection B f2 field, so collection A first document would be

```
f1: 101
f2: 102
f3: 103
f4: 104
f5: 106      
f6: 1025
```

and second would be the same except f6 would be 1026.

Comment: How do you want to distinguish the first and second document in collections A and B?  I.e., what logic and/or decision criteria would you use to assign `"f6"` in collection A given there may be more than one common value of `"f1"` assigned in both collections?

Comment: Just f1, i do not care about whether the order of f6 remains the same. As in, if there are 5 same f1 fields in collection A and B, i want 5 f6 fields written to collection A. But I do not care whether the order of f6 fields is the same in collection A and B. I just care that it only adds fields for f1 fields that matches

Comment: So, if every document in A, and 3 documents in B have the same `"f1"` value, then you want a random selection of 3 A documents to set `"f6" ` from the B docs? What should happen if there are more B docs than A docs that share a common `"f1"` value?

Comment: Ideally it would create a new row in the collection that only has the value of f6 field in collection A and no other information. But I don't happen to particularly care what happens.

An example of a query that does something like this would be nice.